# Optimizing DISTINCT SQL query with OR conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, sql-optimization, sqlperformance

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT business_key
FROM Memory
WHERE concept <> 'case' OR attrib <> 'status' OR value <> 'closed'
```

What I try to achieve is to get all unique business keys that don't have a record concept=case AND attrib=status AND value=closed. Running this query in MySQL with 500 000 records with all unique business_keys is very slow: about 11 seconds.

I placed indices to the business_key column, to the concept, attrib and value columns. I also tried with a combined index to all three columns (concept, attrib, value) but the result is the same.

Here is a screenshot of the `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` command:

[image]

The interesting thing is that running the query without the distinct specifier results in a very fast execution.

I had also tried this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.business_key
FROM Memory m 
WHERE m.business_key NOT IN 
(SELECT c.business_Key 
 FROM Memory c 
 WHERE c.concept = 'case' AND c.attrib = 'status' AND c.value = 'closed')
```

with even worse results: around 25 seconds

Comment: Have you tried changing your ORs to ANDs if that's what you're trying to get out? The reason it's probably slow is that under the hood, it's converting the query into 3 queries (one each for the ORs), and then filtering out the uniques.

Comment: @Neville K: What I am trying to achieve is to get the business keys that DO NOT have row equal to concept=case, attrib=status and value=closed. Therefore I cannot simply use AND. Please, see the update.

Comment: How many from the 500K rows are returned by this query?

Comment: @ypercube: all. all business keys are unique.

Comment: @MartinDimitrov But you haven't answered the question. How many rows does the query return?

Comment: @MartinDimitrov: If all business keys are unique within the table, why do you need to select DISTINCT?

Comment: @Mark Bannister: this is just the sample data. They all happen to be distinct but this is not necessary to be true. So to answer ypercude question the returned rows are 500K.

Comment: After this answer (500K rows returned), I suggest you lower the lengths of the fields so you can create the suggested index and test the `DISTINCT` query only after you add some duplicate data. It's kind of pointless now.

Comment: @ypercube: I don't understand why is it pointless. As I said it is absolutely possible to have all unique business keys. With your suggestion about the combined index, in the `EXPlAIN` command, MySQL says it will use the index. The time dropped with 2 seconds. Could you explain to me why including the business_key in the column made the difference? I thought only the columns in the WHERE clause should be included. Thanks again.

Comment: Because the query only needs to read from the index, and nothing from the table.

Comment: And you are right, it's not pointless if you know what you are doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a compound `(concept, attrib, value, business_key)` index so the query (if MySQL decides to use this index) can find all the info in the index without having to read the whole table.

Your query is equivalent to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT business_key
FROM Memory
WHERE NOT (concept = 'case' AND attrib = 'status' AND value = 'closed')
```

and to this (which will probably yield the same execution plan):

```
SELECT business_key
FROM Memory
WHERE NOT (concept = 'case' AND attrib = 'status' AND value = 'closed')
GROUP BY business_key
```

---

Since the 4 columns that are to be put in the index are all `VARCHAR(255)`, the index length will be pretty large. MyISAM will not allow more than 1000 bytes and InnoDB no more than 3072.

One solution is to cut the length of the last part, making the index length less than 1000: `255+255+255+230 = 995`:

`(concept, attrib, value, business_key(220))`

It will work but it's really not good to have so large index lengths, performance wise.

Another option is to lower the length of all or some of those 4 columns, if that complies with the data you expect to store there. No need to declare length `255` if you expect to have maximum of `100` in a column.

Another option you may consider is putting those 4 columns in 4 separate reference tables. (Or just the columns that have repeated data. It seems that `business_key` will have duplicate data but not that many. So, it won't be much good to make a reference table for that column.)

Example: Put `concept` values in a new table with something like:

```
CREATE TABLE Concept_Ref
( concept_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT
, concept VARCHAR(255)
, PRIMARY KEY concept_id
, UNIQUE INDEX concept_idx (concept) 
) ;

INSERT INTO Concept_Ref
  ( concept )
SELECT DISTINCT
    concept
FROM
    Memory ;
```

and then change the `Memory` table with:

```
ALTER TABLE Memory
ADD COLUMN concept_id INT ;
```

do this (once):

```
UPDATE 
    Memory m
  JOIN
    Concept_Ref c
      ON c.concept = m.concept
SET m.concept_id = c.concept_id
```

and then drop the `Memory.concept` column:

```
ALTER TABLE Memory
DROP COLUMN concept ;
```

You can also add `FOREIGN KEY` references if you change your tables from MyISAM to InnoDB.

After doing the same for all 4 columns, not only the length of new compound index in the `Memory` table will be much smaller but your table size will be much smaller, too. Additionally, any other index that uses any of those columns will have smaller length.

Off course the query would need 4 JOINs to be written. And any `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` statement to this table will have to be changed and carefully designed.

But overall, I think you will have better performance. With the design you have now, it seems that values like `'case'`, `'status'` and `'closed'` are repeated many times.

Comment: This is just the sample data. There will be rows with duplicate business_key

Comment: Well, if you got into trouble creating 500K rows of sample data, you could try to have similar distribution as your expected real data (duplicate business_keys, same percentage of rows with `attrib='status'`, etc).

Comment: When I try to add an index `ALTER TABLE  `memory` ADD INDEX (  `concept` ,  `attrib` ,  `value` ,  `business_key` ) `, the following error prints out: `#1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes`. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Are the fields of `CHAR` or `VARCHAR` type?

Comment: Creating a file with 500K insert statements is not a "trouble" at all. The thing is that such sample data is absolutely plausible.

Comment: concept, attrib, value and business_key are all `VARCHAR(255)`

Comment: One of your fields is too long or the sum of their lengths is too long. There are limitations on the index prefixes. Read here: 1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes

Comment: 4*255 = 1020 which is bigger than 1000. You could make the columns smaller or keep them as they are and make the index use only a part of the fields.

Comment: Please add in your question the table's definition.

Comment: Yes, I read that :) The question is, does this limitation apply to the name of the key or the combined length of the fields?

Comment: the combined length of the index. You could test by adding an index on `(concept, attrib, value, business_key(200) )`

Answer (score 1):

This will allow the use of index. It will still take some time to retrieve all the rows.

```
SELECT DISTINCT business_key FROM Memory 
WHERE NOT(concept = 'case' AND attrib AND 'status' AND value = 'closed')
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the result is the same. Takes 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

If the query runs quickly without DISTINCT, have you tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT business_key from
(SELECT business_key
 FROM Memory
 WHERE concept <> 'case' OR attrib <> 'status' OR value <> 'closed') v
```

?

Comment: Same result. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Comment: wouldn't the original script run slightly better ? I fail to see the improvement. If there really is an improvement, I would like to know.